# How to use Tensorflow queues in real example

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a Tensorflow  DNN model in with I use `feed_dict` to feed the Input 
`Training and Test` data and the labels that belongs to them. To keep things simple  this the important part of the code:

```
def feed_dict(train):
"""Make a TensorFlow feed_dict: maps data onto Tensor placeholders."""
if train == True :
    xs,ys = next_Training_Batch()
    drop_out_value = 0.9
else:
    #Run a test
    xs,ys=  Testing_Data,Testing_Labels
    drop_out_value = 1
return {x:xs,y_:ys,keep_prob:drop_out_value}
for i in range(max_steps):
    if i%5 ==0: # Record summarie and Test-set accruracy
        summary, acc = sess.run([merged,accuracy], feed_dict=feed_dict(False))
        test_writer.add_summary(summary,i)
        #print('Accuracy at steps%s: %s '%(i,acc))
    else:# Record train set summaries and train
        if i%10==0:
            run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
            run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
            summary, _ = sess.run([merged, train_steps],
                          feed_dict=feed_dict(True),
                          options=run_options,
                          run_metadata=run_metadata)
            train_writer.add_run_metadata(run_metadata, 'step%03d' % i)
            train_writer.add_summary(summary, i)
        else:
            summary,_ = sess.run([merged, train_steps], feed_dict=feed_dict(True))
            train_writer.add_summary(summary,i)
```

I've been reading about the TF queue are a way more efficient, I've have huge difficulties get them running, here is what I've done so far:

```
    import tensorflow as tf

'''
# Both Training.csv and Test.csv  include the features values and the and labels as follows :
Feature0  Feature1  Feature2  Feature3  Feature4  Feature5   .......  ClassID(Labels)  onehot
0.200985  1.000000  0.064534  0.415348  0.005391  1.000000             1000             1
0.151232  1.000000  0.048849  0.312474  0.007160  1.000000             2001             2
0.061576  1.000000  0.026125  0.127097  0.017450  1.000000             1000             3
...............................................................................
Each file has > 2500 rows
'''

fileNames = ["Training.csv","Test.csv"]
BATCH_SIZE = 20
number_OF_features  = 450

def batch_generator(fileNames):
    fileNames_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(fileNames)
    reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
    key , values = reader.read(fileNames_queue)
    record_defaults = [[1.0] for _ in range(number_OF_features)]
    content = tf.decode_csv(values,record_defaults = record_defaults)
    features = tf.stack(content[:-2])
    labels = content[-1]
    min_after_dequeue =10 * BATCH_SIZE
    capacity = 20*BATCH_SIZE
    # suffle the data
    data_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([features, labels], batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    capacity =capacity , min_after_dequeue = min_after_dequeue)
    return data_batch , label_batch

with tf.Session() as sess:
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    for _ in range(100 ): # generating 100 batch
        sess.run(batch_generator(fileNames))
        # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        # I just  don'T get how to proceed from this point
        # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

My question is how can I "feed"  data  in train and testing.  I've been reading TF docs but it didn't help.

Ref: The code I wrote is based on this [great tutorials](https://github.com/chiphuyen/tf-stanford-tutorials/tree/master/examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is missing in your code is how you want to use the `data_batch` and `label_batch` tensors. These tensors are of shape `(BATCH_SIZE, number_OF_features)` (resp. `(BATCH_SIZE, 1)`) according this piece of code (assuming `number_OF_features == len(content)-1`):

```
features = tf.stack(content[:-2])
labels = content[-1]
...
data_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([features, labels], batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,...)
```

and the doc of `tf.train.shuffle_batch` (see [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e16cd2ede6a739a1c9c4576ebf8a4fe81e83f39e/tensorflow/python/training/input.py)):

> An input tensor with shape `[x, y, z]` will be output
>     as a tensor with shape `[batch_size, x, y, z]`.

For example you could implement a function which would take as arguments the `data_batch` and `label_batch` and would create and return a `cross_entropy` op. And then you could use this op to train your model with a `GradientDescentOptimizer`.

Your `cross_entropy` op and therefore your `train_op` will depend on your `data_batch` and `label_batch`. So whenever you will ask the `Session` to run `train_op`, it will try to dequeue a new batch from your data queue through `data_batch` and `label_batch`.

For example:

```
# Let's create the batch op
data_batch , label_batch = batch_generator(fileNames)

# Let's use the batch op
cross_entropy = get_cost_op(data_batch, label_batch)
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer().minimize(cross_entropy)


# We're done with the creation of our model so let's train it.
# create NUM_THREADS to do enqueue
qr = tf.train.QueueRunner(queue, [enqueue_op] * NUM_THREADS)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # create a coordinator, launch the queue runner threads.
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    for step in xrange(100): # do to 100 iterations
        if coord.should_stop():
            break
        sess.run(train_op)
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(enqueue_threads)
```

Comment: 1. Thanks for replying,  but how do separate Test and Training set , do I need 2 queues ?

Comment: It's really up to you but the simplest might indeed be to separate your data into 2 lists of files (for training and test purposes) and use 2 different queues (by calling your `batch_generator` twice).

Comment: See for example Section Multiple input pipelines of https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data

Comment: Be aware that [the queues interface is now deprecated](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues), at least in that the [Datasets API](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets) is what is being pushed as its successor and it will no longer be maintained.

Comment: @SamWhitlock can you provide an official link or statement indicating that queues will no longer be supported. I've looked around and all I fund was that it was strongly encouraged to use the Datasets API and no mention of it being depreciated.

Comment: @Lukasz https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/threading_and_queues at the top it says Google has officially stopped development on them. I guess deprecated is the wrong word (i.e. it'll be left in place), but I think the TF team realized that it's very hard to reason about the "threads and queues" model compared to the simpler Datasets API.